# Access 2007 Report Group & Sort gives wrong groups and wrong sorts

Tags: sql, sorting, ms-access, group-by, report

I am using Access 2007 and I have a table with a column of dates in the standard MM/DD/YYYY format, and a column of as currency. I am working with test data and the records span from 1900 to 2175, with one record for each year, with costs ranging from a few hundred to a few thousand dollars.

I have a report that uses this query as its RecordSource:

```
SELECT Year(Appliances.DateReplace) AS Years,
Appliances.CostReplace AS Costs
FROM Appliances;
```

Using the ribbon tool, I have set the Group & Sort to "Group on Years", "from oldest to newest", [custom] "by every 15", "with costs totaled", "with a header section", "with a footer section", and "keep whole group together on one page".

Here is a screenshot of the Group & Sort
[image: screenshot of the Group & Sort]

and here is a screenshot of the first results

[image: screenshot of the first results]

As you can see, the first group contains only 5 records where it should contain 15, and none of the records are in order. The last group (not shown) contains only one record, while the next 18 groups contain the proper 15 results, with the last group containing 1 result.

Adding a secondary Group & Sort that only chooses to Sort by Year will sort the records properly, but it does not fix the number of records shown in the first group.

In the interest of discovering a pattern, I made a list showing the number of records in the first group when I select different intervals for the grouping. The numbers are the interval, followed by the number of records in the first group.

```
1:1,    6:2,    11:3,   16:4,   21:11,
2:2,    7:4,    12:8,   17:4,   22:14,
3:2,    8:4,    13:11,  18:8,   23:9,
4:4,    9:8,    14:4,   19:18,  24:20,
5:5,    10:10,  15:5,   20:20,  25:25
```

The intervals that are multiples of 5 all showed the correct results except for 15, and if there's a pattern to the other ones I am not seeing it except for a lot of 4's.

## Update:

After playing around with this I have discovered that the interval is causing the starting year to change. For example, choosing an interval of 15 causes the report to start counting from 1890, which gives me only 5 records in the first group because my data starts at 1900. I have not seen discovered any pattern in how the starting year relates to the interval that I choose.

Comment: Does CostReplace contain a date?  The year function is being applied to it.

Comment: No, lol. Good catch. CostReplace contains currency and my SQL does not use the Year() function on it, so my brain must have farted while I was formatting my post. I have corrected my post, but I tried adding it to my code anyway to see what would happen and all it did is converted the money to a year and showed that instead of currency. It had no effect on the grouping issue.

Comment: I was thinking you had to have used Sum(Appliances.CostReplace) in the original query or it would have bombed.  How is the custom grouping setup, can you screenshot that as well?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by custom grouping.

Comment: The [Custom] by every 15. Is that by Year(Appliances.DateReplace) ?

Comment: Oh, yes, it's by "Years" which is Year(Appliances.DateReplace). Group by Years from smallest to largest, by every 15. The dropdown menu doesn't give any choice other than the number. It uses the "group by" choice.

Comment: This is definitely a tricky one.  What happens if you try to query SELECT Year(Appliances.DateReplace) AS Years,
Appliances.CostReplace AS Costs
FROM Appliances ORDER BY YEARS.  Does that look correct?

Comment: ORDER BY Years doesn't work (I think "Years" just refers to the object it creates for the report, but I could be mistaken). ORDER BY A.DR and ORDER BY Year(A.DR) both work but don't have any visible effect on the report. I have seen comments on similar questions that say reports ignore your SQL GROUP and ORDER commands entirely in favor of their own group & sort functions.